# String.Replace char to string

Tags: c#, string, char, replace

I would like to replace the french letter Æ with the asci corresponding AE, but the method does not accept this. Is there another way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
myString.Replace("Æ", "AE");
```

Comment: It should be noted that you make use of double quotes, not single ones. Single ones stand for chars, double ones for strings.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `string.Replace('Æ','AE')`, use `string.Replace("Æ", "AE")`.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work?

```
string x = "ÆHELLO";
string y = x.Replace("Æ", "AE");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call `.ToString()` on your char:

```
var str = str.Replace('Æ'.ToString(), "AE");
```

Comment: That seems like a long way around to just putting in: "Æ".  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Coding Gorilla, yes you're right. It's easier to use a string constant here :)

Comment: Ok, I'm one of those dumb US developers that doesn't worry about foreign characters, so I wasn't sure if there was something I didn't know. =)

Answer (score 2):

This should work since it is a valid Unicode character - are you sure you are re-assigning the string? strings are immutable so this is necessary:

```
string test = "Æblah";
test = test.Replace("Æ", "AE");//test is now "AEblah"
```